# ngx-codemirror sql foldgutter not working

Tags: angular, codemirror, ngx-codemirror

Trying to use foldgutter for sql queries in codemirror editor.
Below is the demo where it is not working.
Can anyone please suggest some solution.

Thanks

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-codemirror-2w95pd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate on what is not working in ngx-codemirror?

Comment: I am trying to implement foldgutter for mode 'text/sql'.
added the image above for reference from JSON format.